# Por qué este programa de ReadObject me devuelve null?

Tags: java, archivo, objeto, null

He intentado hacer un programa para leer un objeto llamado Persona que tiene como atributos apellido1, apellido2, nombre y edad. Los tres primeros son Strings y el último un int, y he hecho dos clases: una que me escriba un objeto y la otra que me lo lea. Pues bien, cuando lo voy a leer y hacer un println del getNombre() del objeto que acabo de leer, me sale null. También me sale null para apellido1 y apellido 2 y para el int, un 0.

***El código de la clase que escribe el objeto es este:***

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Persona p1 = new Persona("Pérez", "Rodríguez", "Luis", 20);
        Persona p2 = new Persona("Almodóvar", "Larín", "Pedro", 21);
        Persona p3 = new Persona("Juárez", "Melón", "Enriqueta", 23);
        Persona p4 = new Persona("Estébanez", "Ordóñez", "Francisco", 45);
        
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("ObjetoPersona.obj");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(p1);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        finally{
            if (oos != null){
                try {
                    oos.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Y el código de la clase que lo lee es este:***

```
public class Read {
    
    public static void main (String[] args){
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("ObjetoPersona.obj"));
            
            System.out.println(((Persona)ois.readObject()).getEdad());
        }
        catch(java.io.EOFException ex){
            System.out.println("Fin del fichero");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Read.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Read.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Read.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        finally{
            if (ois != null){
                try {
                    ois.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Read.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

***Clase Persona***

```
public class Persona implements Serializable{
    
    public String apellido1;
    public String apellido2;
    public String nombre;
    public int edad;
    
    public Persona (String apellido1, String apellido2, String nombre, int edad){
        apellido1 = apellido1;
        apellido2 = apellido2;
        nombre = nombre;
        edad = edad;
    }
    
    public String getApellido1() {
        return apellido1;
    }

    public String getApellido2() {
        return apellido2;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sería útil que agregaras tu clase Persona, ¿No estás iniciando mal los atributos de esa clase?. ¿Estás implementando bien los métodos de Persona?. ¿Estás serializando tus datos?

Comment: La acabo de añadir. Como ves es una clase muy sencilla, no creo que esté el fallo ahí. Lo único que se me ocurre que pueda fallar en esa clase es que no he puesto los this en el constructor, pero teóricamente eso no debería de ser un problema.

Comment: has probado a añadir oos.flush() despues de escribir el objeto por el stream?

Comment: No, pero estoy empezando a pensar que es un problema de un JDK. Ayer el NetBeans me estuvo dando problemas y además resulta que cuando lo instalé en su día, en vez de coger el JDK 17, se ve que seleccionó un JDK 8 que tenía de un NetBeans anterior. Total, que me acabé teniendo que descargar el Eclipse porque el NB no iba ni para alante ni para atrás, me aseguré de tener el JDK 17 seleccionado, rehice el código y funcionó, así que no se si será un error de ese código en concreto o algún tipo de problema con el NB o el JDK.

Comment: De hecho el error está en esa clase, deja escribo una respuesta explicando por qué

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás inicializando mal el constructor, pues te sucede algo conocido como *shadowing*. Para evitarlo tendrías que usar la palabra reservada [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

> Dentro de un método de instancia o un constructor, ***this*** es una referencia al objeto actual

```java
public class Persona implements Serializable{
    
    public String apellido1;
    public String apellido2;
    public String nombre;
    public int edad;
    
    public Persona (String apellido1, String apellido2, String nombre, int edad){
        this.apellido1 = apellido1;
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    ...
}
```

## Explicación de tu problema

En java se podría decir que hay 3 tipos de variables

**Variables locales**

> Las variables definidas dentro de métodos, constructores o bloques se denominan variables locales. La variable se declarará e inicializará dentro del método y la variable se destruirá cuando el método se haya completado.

**Variables de instancia**

> Las variables de instancia son variables dentro de una clase pero fuera de cualquier método. Estas variables se inicializan cuando se crea una instancia de la clase. Se puede acceder a las variables de instancia desde dentro de cualquier método, constructor o bloques de esa clase en particular.

**Variables de clase**

> Las variables de clase son variables declaradas dentro de una clase, fuera de cualquier método, con la palabra reservada *static*.

↑↑↑ Traducción del texto de [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-variable-shadowing-in-java) ↑↑↑

Java permite que una clase maneje **distintas variables con el mismo nombre**.
¿Pero cómo distingue cuál es cual?

La respuesta es mediante el orden de acceso, si tenemos una variable local contra una variable de clase o una variable de instancia, al hacer referencia con esa variable, seleccionará la variable local.

Para clarificarlo pongamos un ejemplo:

```java
public class Main {
    
    private String phrase = "Hello World";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printPhrase("Bye cruel World");
    }
    
    public static void printPhrase(String phrase) {
        System.out.println(phrase);
    }
}
```

¿La línea `System.out.println(phrase);` qué imprimirá?
¿El String que enviamos como argumento (variable local) o el String que declaramos al inicio de la clase (variable de instancia)?

La respuesta es que imprime la variable local, es decir, imprime `Bye cruel World`

Entonces eso mismo te está pasando

```java
public Persona (String apellido1, String apellido2, String nombre, int edad) {
    apellido1 = apellido1;
    apellido2 = apellido2;
    nombre = nombre;
    edad = edad;    
}
```

Al tener tu constructor así, le estás diciendo. Asigna el argumento del constructor al argumento del constructor. Por lo que todas tus variables se quedan sin inicializar (de ahí el null)

Con la palabra reservada ***this*** le estarías diciendo, asigna el argumento del constructor a la variable de clase

```java
// variable local     // Variable local
apellido1      =      apellido1;
// variable de clase     // Variable local
this.apellido1     =     apellido1;
```

Comment: Ya había hecho eso alguna vez y no me había dado problemas, pero con programas bastante más sencillos, entonces sí, seguramente sea eso. Cuando consiga solucionar los problemas con el NetBeans lo pruebo y te digo qué tal.

Comment: Me instalé la última versión del NetBeans (tenía la 12.1 y descargué la 12.5) y probé a hacerlo sin añadir los this y funcionó, así que supongo que era cosa del IDE, pero muchas gracias a todos de todas formas.

Comment: @Rurru No es problema del IDE. Que tengas *this* o no es una gran diferencia. Puedes consultar el tutorial de Oracle para que veas qué es lo que pasa, probablemente si te funciona y no usas this, es porque las variables se llaman distinto, o en el peor de los casos, el compilador cambia tu código para corregir ese error (lo que sorprendería mucho)